# How to define offset.retention.minutes different for different consumer groups?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I understand if we define **offset.retention.minutes** in the broker server.property file then all consumer's offsets stored in ***_consumer.offset*** topic will be expired after the configured period in server.property file. But can I define offset.retention.minutes in consumer group property?

Say:

Topic 1 can be consumed by ConsumerGroup1.

Topic 2 can be consumed by ConsumerGroup2.

I want to persist **ConsumerGroup1 committed offset 10 days** and **ConsumerGroup1 committed offset 20 days**. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question - *can messages have their own retention*

No, the retention is defined for the topic, not groups (messages) in the topic.

If you don't want a group to be removed, make sure there's an active consumer always reading from its topics

Comment: I am not asking for the group to be removed or not. I am asking consumers use to commit their offset in the specific topic _consumer.offset topic. I am asking can we persist their committed offset by consumer group level?